# Sylius product show

Tags: e-commerce, product, show, sylius, commerce

I am using sylius e commerce and I have a problem about products.
Acctualy I created one products, and after that I tried to see my product on my shop so i cliked "Show in store" But after that I got an error, and I don't know how to solve it :(

I've been searching on google for solution and I've found it's possible to change 
sylius.locale:                    en_US to en or smth like that but after I do that I still got error:

Catchable Fatal Error: Method Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product::__toString() must return a string value

So I changed my locale back to en_US and after that I'm seeing this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you assign it to the default channel?
Go to `administration/products/new`, select `Channel` tab, check it, and save.

Comment: It works, but could you please explain to me, why does it work only in case I select Channel tab?

Comment: Sylius has the concept of channels: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/channels.html So unless you assign the product to the channel (in your case you only have one channel, which is the default one) it won't show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! :)